# simplexml get node value without typecasting

Tags: php, casting, simplexml

Is there any way to get a node value from a `simplexml` object **without** casting it?

```
$amount = (int)$item->amount;
```

This is not very beautiful in my opinion, I'm searching for a cleaner way but did not find anything so far!

```
//wouldn't this be nice?
$amount = $item->amount->getValue();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP has this build-in. Disliking [type-casting](http://php.net/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) seems to be the issue here, not SimpleXML. But if you insist and prefer calling a function instead, then you might be surprised ;) that there are conversion functions available. In your case it is [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval) and there is also [`strval()`](http://php.net/strval).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the value of a node without having to typecast it? Sure thing! :3

```
class SimplerXMLElement extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public function getValue()
    {
        return (string) $this;
    }
}
```

Now you just have to use `simplexml_load_string()`'s second parameter to get even *simpler* XML elements!

More seriously though, a node is a node. If you need to use the value of a node as a string, integer and what not, it will involve typecasting at one point or another, whether you do it personally or not.

Comment: You are cheating. The value is still typecasted. It's a fair solution, but I find it ironic that you complain about the verbosity of DOM in the comments to my question but then suggest to extend SimpleXml just to be able to have provide functionality that DOM provides out of the box. If you'd do that for all the shortcomings in the SimpleXml API you are just reinventing DOM.

Comment: You're missing the point. That class is a tongue-in-cheek example that typecasting will always occur somewhere whether you're aware of it or not. Sorry you didn't get that.

Comment: @Josh I rather get the impression I somehow insulted your pet XML extension. Or is there any other reason why you are belittling me? Fact is, the OP didnt ask whether PHP typecasts anything under the hood but whether it's possible to fetch a node value from a SimpleXmlElement without explicity casting it in the script. And to that the answer is No unless you like quibble of the sort "it's casted in the instance, not the script". I certainly don't. Like I said, your solution is fair but I still think adding methods to SimpleXml when DOM is available is a waste of time. Feel free to disagree.

Comment: Your "impression" is wrong. I'm sorry that you're taking comments about programming personally. I'll have to reiterate that my class example is "tongue-in-cheek" which is to say that I'm not seriously suggesting to extend the PHP extension blindly. Perhaps it makes sense to some people to do that just to avoid typecasting, but my point is that typecasting will always occur, be it in userland or within PHP.

Comment: @Josh You keep being offensive. Please accept that I do not wish to continue this discussion on this level.

Comment: None of what I wrote was offensive. Perhaps there is a miscommunication here. You are right, however, in saying this discussion is pointless.

Answer (score 4):

No. `SimpleXml` only exposes a very limited API to work with nodes. It's implicit API is considered a feature. If you need more control over the nodes, use [`DOM`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php):

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_string(
    '<root><item><amount>10</amount></item></root>'
);
$node = dom_import_simplexml($sxe->item->amount);
var_dump($node->nodeValue); // string(2) "10"
```

The [`dom_import_simplexml`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php) function will convert the node from a `SimpleXmlElement` to a `DOMElement`, so you are still casting behind the scenes somehow. You no longer need to typecast explicitly though, when fetching the content from the `DOMElement`.

<sup>*On a sidenote: personally, I find `DOM` superior to `SimpleXml` and I'd suggest not to use `SimpleXml` but `DOM` right away. If you want to familiarize yourself with it, have a look at [some of my previous answers about using DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208809+dom).*</sup>

Comment: You're suggesting using a much more complicated way to handle XML for reasons unclear. The OP is looking for a "cleaner" solution, DOM is so infinitely more verbose than SimpleXML that I doubt it'd fit that description.

Comment: @Josh I consider having an API that explicitly communicates what it does to be much cleaner than the implicit interface SimpleXml provides. Yes, DOM is verbose but also much more capable of working with the various node types (of which SimpleXml has no clue). In addition, DOM is a language agnostic interface specification so it pays to learn it over an language specific extension.

Comment: My point is you don't know if Alex needs any of DOM features so you're blindly suggesting DOM for reasons unknown. I don't even know why you're bringing up those node types. I doubt the values Alex is looking for are stashed into PIs. To be fair to users who don't know/need DOM, how about you add an example of loading that XML and retrieving that value as a number or string using DOM?

Comment: @Josh Even if Alex doesnt need ¾ of the features DOM provides right now, there is no disadvantage in using the superior package. SimpleXml is for simple XML UseCases only. DOM is for any XML (and even broken HTML). And it's not like it's rocket science to use DOM. It's easy to use and has a clear and concise API. That alone should be enough to consider it over SimpleXml. As for an example: no, I won't add that. My suggestion to use DOM right away was a sidenote to my answer. Adding an example would put too much emphasis on that. And these is plenty of examples on SO for DOM anyway.

Comment: My point is you don't know Alex's needs. You don't know if he'll ever have to handle DOM manipulation. Perhaps he's just reading data from an external source and all he needs is clean, easy way to do that. Learning DOM to load data from a XML file is akin to learning Javascript to load data from a JSON file. I note that you still haven't demonstrated how to read that value using DOM.

Comment: @Josh Alex's need is "getting the value without typecasting". To that I provided a correct answer, along with a relevant example. I already told you why I won't add any further [examples on how to use DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208809+dom) in my last comment. I also gave plenty of reasoning above as to why I think DOM is superior to SimpleXml as well. I think your comparison is untrue and odd. And I also think it is clear that you and I differ in what we consider a clean and easy to use API. We should leave it at that.

Comment: You forgot to add an example to illustrate that DOM is capable of getting at the values without having to typecast anything, so I added it for you. I hope you won't mind. You're welcome.

Comment: @Josh I've told you two times by now that I won't add it. I don't mind you adding it. Hope you dont mind me correcting it though. It's not necessary to fetch the item first for that example XML.

Comment: When you say you want to *"illustrate that DOM is capable of getting at the values without having to typecast anything"* it is good practice to actually illustrate it, especially when you suggest ditching SimpleXML for DOM. I have removed my name from the code as it has been modified and I can't stand by it anymore.

Comment: @Josh if you look closely, my initial example **does** show how to get the value from the `DOMElement`. `$node->nodeValue` returns the value. That's the relevant part for the OP's question. It's all up there.

Comment: You are suggesting *"not to use SimpleXml but DOM right away"* which is why I think an example using DOM and not SimpleXML is warranted, especially given your claims of "superiority" and lack of "disadvantage." Also, I should mention that the two examples do not behave identically. If I'm not mistaken, the first example targets `/*/item[1]/amount[1]` whereas the second example targets `//amount`. But anyway, the answer is now complete with an actual example and my time is in limited supply so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @Josh I never said they behave identical. And I never said DOM has no disadvantages. That entire discussion apparently stems from you not reading what I am writing. Yes, we do have a communication problem. Let's leave it at that. I am perfectly fine with you disagreeing with my opinion and/or answer.

Answer (score 0):

But it is the safest :). You could create a function to recursively convert the object in an array. Way back when I first starte working with XML in PHP, I remember reaching the conclusion that type casting is just the best method :)

Answer (score 0):

What about xpath way?

```
$amount = $item->amount->xpath('text()');
```