# Wrong simple calculation in PHP

Tags: php, xml, math, curl

I want to perform a very simple calculation with PHP, however, I get the wrong resuls.

My calculation: `20.66 * 1.21` (= approx. 25), PHP gives: `24.20`. I changed the `1.21` to `2`, that gives `40`... So PHP is telling me that `20.66 x 2 = 40`. When I just echo `$resultaat` it gives the right value of `20.66`. (I get the `20.66` value out of an XML file)

I searched for "wrong PHP calculations" here and elsewhere but could not found similar errors. Any ideas?

My code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://URL'); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '25');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
$resultaat = $xml->Balance;
$resultaat2 = $resultaat * 1.21;
$resultaat3 = round($resultaat2, 2);

echo $resultaat3;
```

Comment: Can you show us `var_dump($resultaat);` ?

Comment: 24.20 / 1.21 = 20, exactly. I suggest that the value you're reading from the XML file is coming out as 20, not 20.66, as you believe. You're likely running into the same SimpleXML issue as in [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035163/php-read-decimal-integers-from-xml-attributes), where SimpleXML objects containing floating values are automatically cast to `int` by calculations. Perhaps try `$resultaat = (float) $xml->Balance;` instead of assigning the SimpleXML object to `$resultaat`.

Comment: var_dump($resultaat); -->

object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "20.66"
}

Comment: @MattGibson gave the right answer in the comments,

`$resultaat = (float) $xml->Balance;`

instead of

`$resultaat = $xml->Balance;`

is working.

Comment: I don't have time to make a proper answer right now! Feel free to accept anyone else who gives the right answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$xml->Balance returns a SimpleXmlElement. 
cast it to a double. change this line

```
$resultaat = $xml->Balance;
```

to this

```
$resultaat = (double)$xml->Balance;
```

Answer (score 3):

$resultaat is a SimpleXMLElement not a string or a number. It seems that the type juggling of that class returns an integer value. if you cast the type to double it will work. Here is an example.

```
<?php

$xml = "<xml><value>20.66</value></xml>";
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
var_dump($xmlObj->value); //shows the type
var_dump($xmlObj->value * 2); // 40
var_dump((double)$xmlObj->value * 2); //41.32
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: More information about that problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722653/simplexml-get-node-value-without-typecasting